# Write data from Access to Excel file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to use the following code to write data into an excel file

```
     Dim objexcel As Excel.Application
                     Dim wbexcel As Excel.Workbook
                     Dim wbExists As Boolean
                     Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
                     objexcel.Visible = True
                     On Error GoTo Openwb
                     wbExists = False
                     Set wbexcel = objexcel.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\TAYYAPP\Desktop\test folder\ERROR REPORT2.xls")
                     wbExists = True
Openwb:

                     On Error GoTo 0
                     If Not wbExists Then
                     Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbook.Add
                     End If
```

but I'm getting an

> runtime error object doesn't support property or method

in the line

```
Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbook.Add
```

I have referenced the Excel object library.

Comment: You want the plural - `Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbooks.Add`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to change this line:

```
 Set wbexcel = objexcel.WorkBooks.Open( _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\TAYYAPP\Desktop\test folder\ERROR REPORT2.xls")
```

Note WorkBooks, not Documents

As For this line Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbook.Add, wbexcel is defined as a workbook, but the line is an action, so:

```
objexcel.Workbooks.Add
Set wbexcel = objexcel.ActiveWorkbook
```

EDIT:
As an aside, DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet is probably the easiest way of transferring a set of data (query, table) from Access to Excel.

Comment: thanks that did the job

also for writing data then 
wbexcel.insert "data"

is this syntax ok

Comment: Here is the language reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220733(office.11).aspx. Don't forget that you can record macros and be guided by the code generated.

Comment: @tksy - so how about voting his answer up?!?

Comment: i d like to but i dont have enough reputation for voting

Comment: I have managed to populate the cells with data i want and save it. while saving the file i save it in xls and csv format.

but the csv format is not opening properly is it some encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have  got this code which works fine

```
Dim objexcel As Excel.Application
                     Dim wbexcel As Excel.Workbook
                     Dim wbExists As Boolean
                     Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet
                     Dim objRange As Excel.Range


                     Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
                     objexcel.Visible = True
                     On Error GoTo Openwb
                     wbExists = False
                     Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\TAYYAPP\Desktop\test folder\reports\ERROR REPORT2.xls")
                     Set objSht = wbexcel.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                     objSht.Activate
                     wbExists = True
Openwb:

                     On Error GoTo 0
                     If Not wbExists Then
                     objexcel.Workbooks.Add
                     Set wbexcel = objexcel.ActiveWorkbook
                     Set objSht = wbexcel.Worksheets("Sheet1")

                     End If
```

but I want to add one more check that if the file exists then I want to see if its is populated with values and if so then I want the next set of values to be populated from the end. As of now it is overwriting the existing values